# VB.NET 2010 - Windows Ding.wav playing when pressing Enter inside a TextBox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, listbox, enter

I have a program where you type something into a TextBox and press Enter, then it will add the text into a ListBox and erase the TextBox.
It does work!
However, when Enter is pressed, the `C:\Windows\Media\Windows Ding.wav` audio plays.
It's honestly just annoying...
Anyone know how to stop that?
Thanks!

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to disable the beep after Enter pressed? You can try to set property `SuppressKeyPress` to `True`.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```